# Installing cpan Modules in cygwin fails

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I am trying to install different Perl Modules from CPAN in a cygwin-32bit enviroment and always get Errors of the same kind. This one is from trying to install Net::SSLeay, did make, install and tried force install too, nothing seemed to work.

```
drmariad@drmariad-MOBL ~/.cpan/build/Net-SSLeay-1.70-eDSzRW$ make install

Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
chmod 755 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/auto//Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.dll
/bin/find /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int/auto/ -xdev -name \*.dll /bin/rebase -sOT -
/bin/find: paths must precede expression: /bin/rebase
Usage: /bin/find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
Makefile:731: recipe for target 'pure_install' failed
make: *** [pure_install] Error 1
```

Most of the time it is the bin/find fails message i get in the installations, but i don't know how to change that behaviour. I got errors and failures with most of the modules i tryed to install.

Comment: I think that's suppose to be `... -exec /bin/rebase ...`

Comment: I don't know where that command is coming from.

Comment: What version of ExtUtils::MakeMaker do you have?

Comment: That's the newest. Sorry, but I don't have time to help you debug this. But if the command is in `Makefile`, just add the missing `-exec` and run `make install` again (as a one-time fix).

Comment: Actually, the `-` indicates it's suppose to be `... | /bin/rebase ...`

Comment: worked for now, but i really would like to know, why cpan constantly fails like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My update-to-date Cygwin comes with

- ExtUtils::MakeMaker 6.57_05
- ExtUtils::MM_Cygwin 6.57_07

That's odd for a few reason, but what we care about is that version of MM_Cygwin is buggy.

```
sub install {
    my($self, %attribs) = @_;
    my $s = ExtUtils::MM_Unix::install($self, %attribs);
    return '' unless $s;
    return $s unless %{$self->{XS}};

    my $INSTALLDIRS = $self->{INSTALLDIRS};
    my $INSTALLLIB = $self->{"INSTALL". ($INSTALLDIRS eq 'perl' ? 'ARCHLIB' : uc($INSTALLDIRS)."ARCH")};
    my $dop = "\$\(DESTDIR\)$INSTALLLIB/auto/";
    my $dll = "$dop/$self->{FULLEXT}/$self->{BASEEXT}.$self->{DLEXT}";
    $s =~ s|^(pure_install :: pure_\$\(INSTALLDIRS\)_install\n\t)\$\(NOECHO\) \$\(NOOP\)\n|$1\$(CHMOD) \$(PERM_RWX) $dll\n\t/bin/find $dop -xdev -name \\*.$self->{DLEXT} /bin/rebase -sOT -\n|m if (( $Config{myarchname} eq 'i686-cygwin') and not ( exists $ENV{CYGPORT_PACKAGE_VERSION} ));
    $s;
}
```

You could add the missing `|` to `/usr/lib/perl5/5.14/ExtUtils/MM_Cygwin.pm` as a quick permanent fix.

---

Alternatively, Cygwin has a package named `perl-ExtUtils-MakeMaker` that upgrade the distribution to 7.04_01.

...Except the bug is still present there. If you have this package installed, the file to fix is `/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/ExtUtils/MM_Cygwin.pm`.

---

Alternatively, you can upgrade ExtUtils::MakeMaker to the latest dev release (which uses a completely different command).

```
cpan B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.05_22.tar.gz
```